# How to enable grid footer SummaryType?

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

So I just discovered you can enable the grid footer. And in theory you can show whatever you want in there e.g. display text or sum etc.

[image]

The Text property seems to work. The SummaryType doesn't. I feel like there's a missing step or something.

[image]

Has anyone managed to make the Footer work ? Just so you know, StatusField is not going to cut it here as it won't fit.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the source code for the Sales Order Screen functionality, there is a constant called 'Availability_AllocatedInfo' which is used to construct the 'On-hand...' message in the summary above.  If you search for that, you'll see that there is a 'Availability_FieldSelecting' function that sets that information.  The field called 'Availability' that is updated is what is used to show the status.  Look in the aspx for SO301000, to see all the elements you'll need to replicate the behavior.
Hope that helps

Comment: thanks mate. you're referring to the grid's status field and it's just one very long string at the bottom of the grid. it's not the same as grid footer for each column. I'm trying achieve something similar with this : i.stack.imgur.com/HUict.png

Comment: Ahh, sorry about that.